# Response File with Bearer Header

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How to put Authorization Bearer as Headers in response file?

```
public function downloadExcel($fileName) {
        ob_end_clean();
        return response()->file(resource_path() . '/file_storage/exports/' . $fileName, ['header' => 'Authorization: Bearer ' . request()->bearerToken])->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
    }
```

I am getting unauthorized when trying to download the Excel file. I put my api in in a group where a user is logged in.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve exactly? Are you trying to protect the file download by oAuth2 instead of Laravel authentication?

Comment: Edited my post, @AlexBouma. It is already protected. So, I tried to include Authorization header as the second parameter in `file` method of response. But to no avail. My API is still Unauthorized.

Comment: You are adding the `Authorization` header in the response to the user request. The user should send the `Authorization` header to your server instead. What you are doing here makes no sense to me :) You are sending a bearer token as a response to a request... to authenticated the token should be sent to you!

Comment: Is there another way for this, @AlexBouma? Or should I just put my api outside the group?

Comment: I think the issue is you have a link in your front-end application that opens a new tab to this url to download the excel file and it's protected by OAuth2 right? I am on the right track here? Because then you are unable to add a header to that request because the only way to authorize is using the Authorization header which you cannot set using a regular link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be with having a single page application consuming a oAuth2 protected API and you wanting to let the user download a file, however that is failing since you are unable to set the `Authorization` header on the request.

The best way to solve this is to use the [signed url's](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/urls#signed-urls) feature of Laravel. Return from your API a signed URL (which is only valid for 1 hour for example) and protect your download route not with the oAuth2 middleware but with the instructions in the linked singed url documentation (`signed` middleware).

Your controller action would than just look like:

```php
public function downloadExcel($fileName)
{
   return response()->file(resource_path() . '/file_storage/exports/' . $fileName)
                    ->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
}
```

*Be careful with the `->deleteFileAfterSend(true)` part since that will delete the file from the disk after the first download, this might be intended but I wanted to mention it just in case*

This is the most secure option. There are others but they will require you to put the access token as a GET parameter in the request which is a really bad idea since GET parameters are not encrypted and will show up in access logs for example. So please don't do that :)

Comment: Thanks for this. I haven't check it before. Unfortunately, this feature is not available for my laravel version which is 5.3. Should i use this [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/lab66/laravel-url-signer) instead?

Comment: I would say upgrade :) But this package looks legit although I have never used it myself so I can’t say much about it. But if it does what it says in the README this looks about the same as the original package.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public function downloadExcel($pathToFile)
{
    $headers =[
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer XXXXXX',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
    ];

    return response()->file($pathToFile, $headers);
}
```

Comment: This is the wrong way around as far as I understand the issue. The server never adds a `Authorization` header as a response to a client request, that doesn't make much sense.